# svgjs transform imported element

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

Using svg.js I am able to import a fragment from an existing svg file and add it to the dom. However I am not able to then manipulate that element using svg.js.
Here is my code.

```
$.get('img/sprite.svg', function (doc) {

        var figure = $(doc).find('g#figure')[0];       
        var figureHTML = figure.outerHTML;

        var added = draw.svg(figureHTML);
        added.transform({rotate: 90});
});
```

Here is the link to the docs for importing
http://svgjs.dev/importing-exporting/
and the links for transforming
http://svgjs.dev/manipulating/transforms/
I can't get any transformations to work on the imported element.

Comment: did you doublecheck the generated svg? Which element will get the transformation? Transformation of `<svg>` dont work!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is another way, but if one uses css selectors one can get a handle  into the objects in question then the transformations work.

```
   var elements = SVG.select('g#figure')
                .transform({rotate: 90});
```

http://svgjs.dev/referencing/